# Delegation Poker with more than two interested parties

Tags: team-management, responsibility

Delegation Poker is a Management 3.0 workout practice that differentiates delegation on seven levels. This works fine for two interested parties: the manager and the team.

**But how can it be made to work for three or more parties?** For example, Scrum has three main roles: Product Owner, Scrum Master and development team. More if you also count the project sponsor and/or the end-user.

> For reference, the [seven levels of delegation](https://management30.com/product/delegation-poker/) according to M3.0 are:
>
> 1. Tell: You as the manager make the decision.
> 2. Sell: You make the decision but you try to persuade others to buy into it.
> 3. Consult: You get input from team before still making decision.
> 4. Agree: You make a decision together as a team.
> 5. Advise: Your team makes the decision, but you try to influence it.
> 6. Inquire: Your team makes the decision and then tells you about it.
> 7. Delegate: You offer no influence and let team work it out.

Comment: hmm i think this kind of game misses the point of scrum

Comment: It's not a game, really. The name "Poker" misses the mark, I think. Then again, "Planning Poker" isn't a game either.

Comment: You're probably going to have better luck contacting Jurgen direct. He's pretty good about responding to inquiries.

Comment: Check this blog post, where one writes about his experiences incl. introducing more roles: http://www.ontheagilepath.net/2013/09/delegation-poker-and-delegation-board.html?m=1

Comment: @Tobias The blog post is an excellent suggestion. It actually gives a brilliant solution for a decision_chain_, thus breaking it down to sets of two parties again. For more than two parties, I think I'll dare take Joel advice and contact Jurgen Appelo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for completeness. This seems to be a helpful answer:

Check this blog post, where one writes about his experiences incl. introducing more roles: http://www.ontheagilepath.net/2013/09/delegation-poker-and-delegation-board.html?m=1